# Can't do anything with Ext. HDD, ".Trashes" is probably the boogyman. (On a MAC!)

Tags: permissions, external-hard-drive, trash

I bought an external hard drive today. It's a Samsung. But I'm not able to do anything with it. A few notes on that:

- I can't put anything on the hard drive. It keeps on 'preparing copying
  files'.
- I can delete anything on the hard drive *system files*, except the
  folder ".Trashes". It gives error 'Unexpected error: -50'.
- I've tried to empty my own trashcan, no changes.
- I've set the file permission on the .Trashes to read/write everyone,
  doesn't change a thing.
- Trying to format the whole drive with Disk Utility, but quits at
  start, because the drive cannot be deactivated.

I've tried a few terminal commands:

- `sudo -s -r rf /Volumes/Untitled\ 1/.Trashes` - Directory not empty
- `-r rf /Volumes/Untitled\ 1/.Trashes` - no permissions

Also:

- `cd /Volumes ls -al cd name_of_partition ls -al`
- `-rm -rf .Trashes`

Again: Permission error.

Also:

- I can't change drive permissions via Disk Utility, via the button 'recover drive permissions', because it is 'blank'.

I really can't figure out how to delete .Trashes, format the drive or get the damn thing working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to erase the drive.  Go into Disk Utility, click on the drive in the left area and from the tab options on the right `First Aid`, `Erase`, `Partition`, etc. choose `Erase`.  Click the `Erase` button to start the erase process.  This will write a fresh partition map and HFS+ filesystem onto the drive, overwriting the partition the manufacturer left on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to erase than try below method:

Go to the trash folder, go in the deep at the last of the trash directory where you find only files and cannot go deeper, copy and paste some file (e.g. from desktop some .txt file) there. and try to empty trash again.

This worked for me after searching a lot and trying every method including terminal and power shell commands.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem, and using `sudo` worked for me

Try `sudo ls -la .Trashes` and `sudo rm -rf .Trashes`

Comment: This question is from 7+ years ago and they clearly state they tried the `rm -rf .Trashes` method and it didn’t work.